# Databinding Grid position - wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, grid

I have a grid, which I build dynamically and while building I put an image in the first cell (0, 0) in the grid.

I want to use data binding so that when the users change the position, the image will change its position to the right place in the grid.

The user has 2 texboxes which there he put the row and column in the grid.

Any help will be appreciated.

Edit:
The code I did so far:
View:
    I have a window that contains thisuser controller

```
public MyController()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.playerImage = new Image();
    }

    public void CreateGrid(string ansFromServer, int numberOfRows, int numberOfCols, int type)
    {
        this.rows = numberOfRows;
        this.cols = numberOfCols;
        for (int i = 0; i < this.rows; i++)
        {
            RowDefinition def = new RowDefinition();
            mainGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(def);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < this.cols; i++)
        {
            ColumnDefinition def = new ColumnDefinition();
            mainGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(def);
        }
}
```

Comment: Post some of your code showing what you have tried so far

Comment: What do you mean by "when the user change the position"? What does the user do?

Comment: the user insert to 2 textbox the row and column

Comment: Bind the `Grid.Column` and `Grid.Row` properties of the Image to two `int` properties in your view model, like `Grid.Column="{Binding GridColumn}"`.

Comment: Clemens, can you please tell me how to do that in the code behind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a simple view model with two integer properties for the column and row:

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private int gridColumn;
    public int GridColumn
    {
        get { return gridColumn; }
        set { gridColumn = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    private int gridRow;
    public int GridRow
    {
        get { return gridRow; }
        set { gridRow = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

and use it in XAML e.g. like this:

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:ViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBox Width="50"
                 Text="{Binding GridColumn, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        <TextBox Width="50"
                 Text="{Binding GridRow, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <Grid Grid.Row="1">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Image Source="C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Koala.jpg"
               Grid.Column="{Binding GridColumn}" Grid.Row="{Binding GridRow}"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

In case you've created the Image control in code behind, you would set the bindings like this:

```
playerImage.SetBinding(Grid.ColumnProperty, new Binding("GridColumn"));
playerImage.SetBinding(Grid.RowProperty, new Binding("GridRow"));
mainGrid.Children.Add(playerImage);
```

Comment: thank you very very much :)
I really appriciate it!! 
But how do I do the binding in the code behind?
I create the grid in the code behind :/

Comment: @DvirSamuel You should edit your question and show us what you did so far. That would make it much easier to answer your question.

Comment: I would like to bind the playerImage

Comment: Take a look at the bottom of my post.